# Positive definite matrix in a Banach lattice algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a Banach lattice algebra. If $\textbf{A}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with all enteries in $V$. Is there any concept of positive definiteness for $\textbf{A}$ ?? Since $V$ is an algebra so multiplication makes sense.

Comment: What do you think Sir? the concept of positive definiteness for such matrix should be same as for the case of real valued matrices?

Comment: Do you have a notion of positivity for elements of $V$? If so, the same notion of $n$-positivity for $C^*$-algebras generalizes.

Comment: yes. $V$ is endowed with ordering say $\leq$. Do I have to show that for $\textbf{A}=[a_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^n$, every $a_{ij}\geq 0$ ???

Comment: That's not what is done in the $C^*$-case. If $V$ is a $C^*$-algebra, then so is $M_n(V)$, so positivity means self-adjoint with spectrum in $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Yes! But I have not specified what kind of positivity is it. I am just considering an arbitrary vector space endowed with some ordering.